# User defined types - units, conversions

Tags: c++

I'm try to make some user defined type to express units so that I can strongly type function parameters.  For example, millimeters for lengths, millimeters per second for velocity, and millimeters per second per second for acceleration, and the likes.

I have done this so far:

```
template<typename T, typename mksUnit>
struct Value
{
    // data member
    T val;

    // constructor
    constexpr explicit Value(T d) : val(d) {}

    // operator overloads
    Value & operator +=(const Value &rhs) { val += rhs.val; return *this; }
    // other math and compare
    // operators, etc.
}

template<int meters, int kilo, int seconds>
struct mksUnit
{
    enum { m = meters, k = kilo, s = seconds };
};
```

With this, I can do things like:

```
using meters = Value<double, mksUnit<1, 0, 0>>;
using mm = Value<double, mksUnit<-3, 0, 0>>;
constexpr mm operator""_mm(long double v) { return mm(static_cast<double>(v)); }
using mmpersec = Value<double, mksUnit<-3, 0, 1>>;
constexpr mmpersec operator""_mms(long double v) { return mmpersec(static_cast<double>(v)); }
using mmpersec2 = Value<double, mksUnit<-3, 0, 2>>;
constexpr mmpersec2 operator""_mms2(long double v) { return mmpersec2(static_cast<double>(v)); }
```

to create units that I can use like:

```
mm dist = 5.5_mm;
mm dist1 = dist + 10_mm;
mmpersec velocity = mmpersec(50.0);
mmpersec2 accel = 100.0_mms2;

void set_accel(mmpersec2 accel) { _accel = accel; }
```

etc.

I have the need to do conversions between some of the types, and I'm looking for a good way to do it.  The only idea I have is to inherit from the classes and add the type overloads to the derived classes.

```
struct millimeters: public mm
{
    operator(meters) { return mm.val / 1000; }
}
```

or something like that.

I want to do things like:

```
meters len = meters(5.0);
len += millimeters(25);
```

Which should set len to 1.025, for example.

My question is what is the best way to add conversions between different user defined types that are derived as shown above.

Comment: This is really mind-bendingly strange. Why use tempates at all here? Are you living in a universe where the definition of what a `mm` is can fluctuate on a compile-to-compile basis? These things are as close to constants as you're ever going to get.

Comment: I have a feeling you're tackling this the wrong way. You probably want a single type for fundamental units such as time, distance, weight or mass, and temperature. A function that needs mass and time can be checked at compile time. Any conversion you need to do can be done internally by normalizing all values to some kind of internal standard such as mm, seconds, °K or whatever.

Comment: That approach leads to code like `unit::energy momentum(const unit::mass& m, const unit::veolocity& v)` where you can also have `unit::velocity(const unit::distance& d, const unit::time& t)` as a constructor. You can have convenience constructors for things like *mph* or *inch-pounds* or whatever units you're actually applying in your problem.

Comment: If you can use the boost libraries, there is already a [units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) library that is decent at working with SI quantities.

Comment: We don't use boost.  I am aware that they have a units library.  I have found some other ones as well, but they seem unduly complex.  I need a fairly small subset of what they offer.

Comment: have a look at [std::ratio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) and the related templates

Comment: @tadman - the ideas here, and a lot of the code, is based upon the keynote presentation at cppcon 2012 by Bjarne Stroustrup.  The talk was on C++ style.  The relevant location in the presentation is about 20 minutes in.

Comment: I don't think you understand what Bjarne Stroustrups code is about. `using mm = Value<double, mksUnit<-3, 0, 0>>;` Your mksUnits parameter refers to the prefix notion of a unit, but in Stroustrups code it refers to the quantity of length to the power of -3, namely m^-3 or 1(m/3). He advises the same principles that i used in my answer.

Comment: I literally copied the code from his slides.  The bullet point on the slide says "We can define Units to be handled at compile time".  The comment in his code says  "a unit in the mks system", and "a magnitude with a unit", and "meters/second type".  The concept seems to be creating 'types' that couple a 'magnitude' with a 'unit', to create type safe code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you tackle your problem from the wrong direction. You do not want to transform arbitrary units, but units within a quantity.

So I would start like this:

```
struct Quantity {
    double value;
};

// Base Quantites
class Length : public Quantity {};
class Duration : public Quantity {};

// Base units
Length Meter() {
    Length l;
    l.value = 1;
    return l;
}

Length Millimeter() {
    Length l;
    l.value = 0.001;
    return l;
}

Duration Seconds() {
    Duration t;
    t.value = 1;
    return t;
}
```

Now we got our quantities sorted out, we can start conversion:

```
// It is a good Idea to use SFINAE here to enable this function
// only for derived classes of Quantity
template <class Quantity>
double transform(Quantity&& value, Quantity&& ratio) {
    return value.value / ratio.value;
}
```

The part for derived units is the tricky one:

```
template <class Q1, class Q2>
struct MultipliedQuantiy : public Quantity {};

// I would use SFINAE here too because it is a bad idea to 
// define a multiplication for all possible types.
template <class Q1, class Q2>
auto operator*(Q1 q1, Q2 q2) {
    MultipliedQuantiy<Q1, Q2> q;
    q.value = q1.value * q2.value;
    return  q;
}
```

And as an example we can use this:

```
auto area = 1000.0*Millimeter()*(1000.0*Millimeter());
auto squareMeter = 1.0*Meter()*Meter();
double area_in_m2 = transform(area, squareMeter);
```

So this is the basic idea, on how it can be done. Imlementing the rest of the operations is up to you. You can also use constexpr in a lot of places to force compile time evaluation.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to create units that can be used like 'normal' data types, but that don't allow implicit conversions.  Using extra functions like your 'transform' take away from the natural use of types that would know how to convert without added syntax.  The data types I described and implemented above work very naturally, and make it impossible to inadvertently mix meters with mm, or degrees with radians.  I would just like to come up with an elegant way to do confersions so I could do math and assignments without using the likes of your transform function.

Comment: Why do you want to make implicit conversion impossible? Your physical background is the same, no matter if you input mm oder meter, both is a length and it is a skalar quantity. So why would you want to prevent someone to do an operation on meter and mm?

Comment: adding mm to meters is ok, so long as mm knows how to convert to meters.  If I say mm = double, meters = double, add mm to meters, I have a bad answer.  If mm = double, mm = int, adding is still possible due to implicit conversion, but the answer is not likely what I want.  I want to make sure that interfaces know that the data units are directly compatible, not implicitly converted somewhere.

Comment: You should stop thinking about adding Millimeters and Meters and start thinking about adding two lengths. If the underlying representation of the same quantity is different over the operands of a operations (e.g. addition), than this is a whole new problem for itself and will get you into more trouble. If you are not very familiar with templates in c++, you should not atempt implementing it, because it will add much boilerplate code to your problem. And even if you implemented it correctly you run consistency problems, because your precision changes along your computation.

Comment: Assume the following operation: `Millimeter<int>(Meter<double>(0.1) / 3)^2`. This will result in in 9mm^2. while the calculation done in float will lead to 11,1mm^2. Your error is already 2.1mm and you have 0 significant digits.

Comment: I guess an important point that is missing, is that I intend to pass these types through interfaces.  This means I need types, not functions that allow me to create millimeters out of meters.  I want to have functions know that the units of the data being passed are correct, in an environment where I have mixed units at different interface points.  Sometimes the units are mm, sometimes encoder counts that translate to mm.  I want to make it clear at all interface points what the units are, and have it enforced by the compiler, not the programmer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156554/discussion-between-outofbound-and-ttemple).